# Unable to translate code snippet on dates between C# to android

Tags: java, c#, android

i need to convert this C# code to android java.

```
 This = Convert.ToDateTime("14/01/2020 00:00:00");
        Past = Convert.ToDateTime("01/01/1988 00:00:00");
        difference = This - Past;
        MINUTE = (int)difference.TotalMinutes;
        MessageBox.Show(MINUTE.ToString());
```

i try many things, but error resault.... i try this:

```
 DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    try {
         This = df.parse(date);
         Past =  df.parse("01/01/1988");
         diff =  This.getTime() - Past.getTime();
    }
    catch (Exception r) {
    }
    return String.valueOf(diff);
```

for example, the result that i need to get:

```
16849440  =  14/01/2020
16850880  =  15/01/2020
16852320  =  16/01/2020
```

Unable to reach this values

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need to find the difference in minutes between two dates.

This snippet uses built-in TimeUnit class to do the conversion.

```
long diffInMinutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(diff);
```

Comment: thanks for the help. in this sample and with my code i got for 16/01/2020 - 16855200 and i need to get: 16852320 (like i got in my C# sample)